# Unwanted side effects when flattening a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, flat

I was just testing some algorithms to flatten a list, so I created 3 lists inside a list, and then tried to flatten it. I never touch the original list, the variables are named different, but when I try to see the original list, it has been modified, any idea why this is happening?

```
In [63]: xxx =  [['R', 'L', 'D'], ['U', 'O', 'E'], ['C', 'S', 'O']]

In [64]: def flat_ind(lst):
    ...:     one = lst[0]
    ...:     for l in lst[1:]:
    ...:         one += l
    ...:     return one
    ...:

In [65]: flat = flat_ind(xxx)

In [66]: flat
Out[66]:  ['R', 'L', 'D', 'U', 'O', 'E', 'C', 'S', 'O']

In [67]:  xxx
Out[67]:
[['R', 'L', 'D', 'U', 'O', 'E', 'C', 'S', 'O'],
 ['U', 'O', 'E'],
 ['C', 'S', 'O']]
```

I understand that `one` is still pointing to the original `lst` and that is the reason it is modifying it, but still, I though that, since this was inside a function, it would not happen, more importantly

how do I make this not happen?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to deep copy the list. Or try `one = lst[0][:]`

Comment: The name `xxx` and the name `lst` inside the function point to the same actual list in memory. To pass a copy of the list to the function, you need to first copy the `xxx` list. Check out `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: @rdas there is no need to deepcopy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I understand that one is still pointing to the original lst and that is the reason it is modifying it, but still, I though that, since this was inside a function, it would not happen,"

That doesn't make any sense. It doesn't matter where you mutate an object, *it will still be mutated*.

In any case, the mutation occurs because of this:

```
one += l
```

which is an in-place modification. You could use

```
one = on + l
```

instead, but that would be highly inefficient. As others have pointed out, you could just copy that first list,

```
one = lst[0][:]
```

But the idiomatic way to flatten a regularly nested list like this is to simply:

```
flat = [x for sub in xxx for x in sub]
```

Or,

```
from itertools import chain
flat = list(chain.from_iterable(xxx))
```